# Como recuperar todas as ocorrências [[xxx]] de uma string em PHP?

Tags: php, string, placeholder

Tenho um texto com placeholders `[[xx]]`, `[[ccvf]]`, `[[dfg]]`, etc.
O texto dentro do placeholder é indeterminado e a quantidade de placeholders é variável.

Então no seguinte texto como eu poderia ter uma array com todos os placeholders?

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet imperdiet sapien, [[xx]] vitae luctus augue convallis quis. Pellentesque felis eros, dignissim vitae [[ccvf]] dignissim sed, porta a leo. Duis tincidunt, ex sit amet sollicitudin vehicula, nibh velit ultrices ipsum, at feugiat enim arcu et [[dfg]] enim.
```

Resultado desejado:

```
$placeholders = ['xx','ccvf','dfg']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/369919/112052) (que não está errada), você usa a [*flag*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `U`, que faz com que o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` não seja [*greedy* (ganancioso)](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap), tornando-o [*lazy* (preguiçoso)](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution). É o mesmo que usar `/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/` - usar `.*?` sem *flag* `U` tem o mesmo efeito de usar `.*` com a *flag*, e ambas funcionam perfeitamente. Só gostaria de propor uma alternativa.

Apesar de `.*?` (ou `.*` com a *flag* `U`, que são a mesma coisa) funcionar, [os quantificadores *lazy* têm o seu preço](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_expensive). Basicamente, a regex tem que ficar indo e voltando várias vezes na string, para encontrar um trecho que a satisfaça. E como o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, as possibilidades que a regex precisa verificar [podem aumentar exponencialmente](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), dependendo do caso (não é o caso da sua regex, mas mesmo assim é importante saber disso e não usar `.*` sempre, "no automático").

Em regex, o melhor é [dizer exatamente o que você quer e o que não quer](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want). O ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, mas você realmente quer que tenha "qualquer coisa" entre `[[]]`?

Uma alternativa seria usar `'/\[\[([^\[\]]*)\]\]/'`. Eu troquei o ponto por `[^\[\]]`, que é uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). Ou seja, ela corresponde a qualquer caractere que **não** seja o que está entre `[^` e `]`. No caso, é `\[\]`, ou seja, é qualquer caractere que não seja `[` nem `]`. Assim, eu nem preciso da *flag* `U`, pois o quantificador `*` vai parar quando encontrar o primeiro `]` (ou outro `[`, evitando casos como `[[[`, que entendi que não deve aparecer).

A diferença de desempenho, neste caso, não é tão grande, mas a classe de caracteres negados é ligeiramente mais rápida: [veja a versão com `.*`](https://regex101.com/r/LtLm6l/1/debugger) e compare a quantidade de passos com a [segunda versão](https://regex101.com/r/sJJabT/5/debugger). Claro que para poucas strings pequenas, a diferença será imperceptível. **Mas há outra diferença entre essas soluções.**

Caso a string tenha um *placeholder* incompleto (por exemplo, `[[abc]` - com um `]` faltando, talvez por erro de digitação - ou `[[abc` - sem o fechamento), a regex com `.*` acaba pegando mais caracteres do que devia (já que o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, inclusive os próprios caracteres `[` e `]`, e caso a regex julgue necessário, o ponto pega o `[` ou o `]` como parte do *match*). Exemplo:

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum [[xx] et [[dfg]] abc [[ops abc [[xyz]]";
preg_match_all('/\[\[(.*)\]\]/U', $str, $pat_array);
var_dump($pat_array);
preg_match_all('/\[\[([^\[\]]*)\]\]/', $str, $pat_array);
var_dump($pat_array);
```

A saída deste código é:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "[[xx] et [[dfg]]"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "[[ops abc [[xyz]]"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "xx] et [[dfg"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "ops abc [[xyz"
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "[[dfg]]"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "[[xyz]]"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "dfg"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "xyz"
  }
}
```

Repare que a primeira regex com `.*` acaba pegando `xx] et [[dfg` e `ops abc [[xyz`, pois ela não consegue detectar que o `xx` só tem um `]` e o `ops` não possui o fechamento. E como o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, a regex continua avançando na string até encontrar alguma ocorrência de `]]`. Por isso ela acaba pegando mais do que devia.

Já se eu usar `[^\[\]]*`, a regex para quando encontra um `[` ou `]`, e caso não encontre, a regex falha e ela pode continuar procurando em outros pontos da string. Por isso ela só encontra os *placeholders* que possuem a abertura (`[[`) e fechamento (`]]`), ignorando os demais casos.

Além disso, a segunda regex é mais eficiente e demora menos para detectar e ignorar esses problemas. Compare a [quantidade de passos da primeira regex](https://regex101.com/r/rJNnZM/4/debugger) com a [da segunda](https://regex101.com/r/cVIZcl/4/debugger). Novamente, para poucas strings pequenas a diferença de desempenho não será tão grande, e se todas as strings possuem *placeholders* corretamente delimitados (ou seja, caso não ocorram os problemas de faltar o `]` no fechamento), este problema não ocorrerá.

---

Se quiser ser ainda mais específico, pode colocar uma regex que corresponda exatamente àquilo o *placeholder* pode ser. Se ele só pode ter letras, por exemplo, basta usar `'/\[\[([a-zA-Z]*)\]\]/'`. O trecho `[a-zA-Z]` corresponde a qualquer letra de `a` a `z`, maiúscula ou minúscula.

Outro detalhe é que o `*` significa "**zero** ou mais ocorrências", então ele pode acabar pegando a string `[[]]`. Se quiser forçar que tenha pelo menos um caractere entre o `[[` e `]]`, troque para `'/\[\[([a-zA-Z]+)\]\]/'`, pois o `+` significa "**uma** ou mais ocorrências" (ou seja, tem que ter pelo menos uma letra entre os colchetes). Outra opção é usar valores fixos, como `'/\[\[([a-zA-Z]{3,20})\]\]/'` (aceita entre 3 e 20 letras) ou ainda `'/\[\[([a-zA-Z]{3,})\]\]/'` (no mínimo 3 letras, sem limite máximo). Adapte de acordo com o que precisar.

Answer (score 1):

Achei a resposta:

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet imperdiet sapien, [[xx]] vitae luctus augue convallis quis. Pellentesque felis eros, dignissim vitae [[ccvf]] dignissim sed, porta a leo. Duis tincidunt, ex sit amet sollicitudin vehicula, nibh velit ultrices ipsum, at feugiat enim arcu et [[dfg]] enim."

preg_match_all ("/\[\[(.*)\]\]/U", $str, $pat_array);
```

result:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "[[RegAPR]]"
    1 => "[[AnnualFees]]"
    2 => "[[SpecialOffer]]"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "RegAPR"
    1 => "AnnualFees"
    2 => "SpecialOffer"
  ]
]
```